# webpack built failed with unparsable error but in node the line works

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, webpack

I am using Node V6.11.0 and npm 3.10.10. Recently I am thinking of using markdown-it and one of the dependencies is entities. Before I add this dependency things are working fine, but then when I try to install `npm install markdown-it --save` and build again I received this error as below:

```
> access_mgr@0.0.1 build /home/jgu/repos/access_mgr
> webpack --config webpack.config.js --progress --colors

Hash: 05d4660f200286bd0530  
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 13572ms
                        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                  favicon.ico  1.41 kB          [emitted]  
 main-05d4660f200286bd0530.js   2.2 MB       0  [emitted]  main
main-05d4660f200286bd0530.css   435 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 274 hidden modules

ERROR in ./~/entities/maps/entities.json
Module parse failed: /home/jgu/repos/access_mgr/node_modules/entities/maps/entities.json Unexpected token (1:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:9)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/home/jgu/repos/access_mgr/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/home/jgu/repos/access_mgr/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (/home/jgu/repos/access_mgr/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:581:61)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (/home/jgu/repos/access_mgr/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:966:10)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/home/jgu/repos/access_mgr/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:730:24)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlock (/home/jgu/repos/access_mgr/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:981:25)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/home/jgu/repos/access_mgr/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:709:33)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/home/jgu/repos/access_mgr/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/home/jgu/repos/access_mgr/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/home/jgu/repos/access_mgr/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/home/jgu/repos/access_mgr/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/home/jgu/repos/access_mgr/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/home/jgu/repos/access_mgr/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/home/jgu/repos/access_mgr/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at /home/jgu/repos/access_mgr/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (/home/jgu/repos/access_mgr/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at /home/jgu/repos/access_mgr/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:446:3)
 @ ./~/markdown-it/lib/common/entities.js 6:17-55
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
        + 7 hidden modules
```

Then I run node REPL and pasted `require('entities/maps/entities.json');` and it is fine. I checked that json file it is just a mapping of name to special unicode symbols. Anything I missed causing the webpack built to fail?

Comment: It's asking for a loader. Do you have `json-loader` as one of your loaders configured into webpack?

Comment: Thanks. I am still using the old version of webpack 1.13.1. adding json-loader made it work

Comment: Webpack 1 still requires `json-loader`, however webpack 2 doesn't [more info here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#json-loader-is-not-required-anymore)